# AutoRun on a USB (Windows 10)

Tags: java, windows, usb, autorun

I have a JAR file which I would like to put into a USB, and then have it so that the USB will automatically run the JAR as soon as it is plugged in. I've heard that there are some restrictions regarding AutoRun in Windows 10, so how would I do this? I've never worked with anything of this sort before.

Comment: This kind of question is more on-topic on the [SuperUser SE](https://superuser.com). [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/1445659/windows-10-autorun-a-batch-file)'s a similar question on that StackExchange.

Comment: What Aaron says, plus: You're best adviced to **not do this**. From security point of view, it's a horrible idea to plug some storage device in a computer and auto-launch an application stored on it. You'll see lots of effort put into avoiding exactly this, by OS programmers and a ton of security related software creators, so you'll not enjoy the outcome of your idea.